# To use a non-initial value for a variable

Tags: c++

Consider the following example of a code:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
    MyClass( float f, char a );

    private:
    int b;
};
```

By declaring like this, is the initial value of **integer b** is set to zero by deafult?

If this is possible, can I change the value of b like:
(bear in mind that the following code will be called a number of times and the value assigned to b each time is required for the next iteration of the procedure)

```
int fg = int(ds/r);
int temp1;
if(b==0) {
    temp1=0;
}

temp1=b;
b=fg;
```

Comment: Aside from the answers, someone minds explaining why: int b; cout << b << endl; results in 0 though?

Comment: @FlorisVelleman: If `b` has static storage duration, then it will be zero-initialised. Otherwise, its initial value is unspecified, and might or might not be zero. In the question, it's a class member so its storage duration is that of the object that contains it.

Answer (score 3):

By default it is not initialized.

In C++ 11 you can just write:

```
private:
    int b = 0;
```

Now any constructor of the class will initialize value of `b` with `0` if you don't explicity say otherwise

Answer (score 2):

> By declaring like this, is the initial value of integer b is set to zero by deafult?

It all depends on the implementation of your constructor. If you don't do anything about it, then the value of `b` is unspecified.

To ensure it is set to `0`, you would need something like this in your constructor(s) implementation(s):

```
 MyClass::MyClass( float f, char a ) : b() {}
```

Note that in C++11 you can initialize a data member at the point of declaration, so you can do this:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    MyClass( float f, char a );

  private:
    int b = 0; // or int b{0}, but not int b(0)
};
```

Comment: `MyClass::MyClass( float f, char a ) : b(0) {}` ?

Comment: @W.B. not necessary, `b()` will do fine. But some prefer to be explicit about it, which is OK.

Comment: Interesting. I know that bool default was false, didn't know that about int.

Answer (score 1):

variable `b` is not initialized to `0` if you don't initialize it in constructor(suggest initialize it in member initializers list)

```
MyClass( float f, char a ) : b(0) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Th variable is uninitialised, which means that its value is undefined (random trash).

You can set the values like you want. There's no problem with that (as long as b has been initialised).